# Non-constant timing in Android game loop

Tags: android, loops, timing

I am developing a game for Android. Since it is my first game for Android, I wanted to keep it as simple as possible. I want to display a sequence of random numbers (one at a time). Between each pair of numbers a given amount of time should pass (I am currently using 500ms).

The problem is that the delay between two numbers is not constant (neither on the emulator nor on an actual device running Android 2.3.4). Most of the time the numbers change at a constant rate, but sometimes a significant and noticeable delay appears (even reaching more than 1 second).

I include the parts of the code responsible for rendering the numbers. I am using a SurfaceView and the following part is the `run()` method of the game loop implemented in an additional thread:

```
while (!mDone) {
    long now = System.nanoTime();
    if (mLastTime == -1) mLastTime = now;
    long delta = now - mLastTime;
    if (delta > 500000000) {
        mNumberBox.update();
        mLastTime = now;
    }

    if ((w > 0) && (h > 0)) {
        Canvas canvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        if (canvas != null) {
            mRenderer.drawFrame(canvas);
            mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

`mNumberBox.update()` updates the number to be drawn and it is supposed to be called every 500ms. Its code is very simple:

```
mCurrNumber = mRand.nextInt(9) + 1;
```

`mRenderer.drawFrame()` is the responsible for rendering the number on the screen. Here is the code:

```
canvas.drawRoundRect(mBoxRect, 45, 45, mBoxPaint);
String numStr = String.format("%d", mCurrNumber);
Rect bounds = new Rect();
mTextPaint.getTextBounds(numStr, 0, 1, bounds);
int height = bounds.bottom - bounds.top;
canvas.drawText(numStr, canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2 + height / 2, mTextPaint);
```

I have profiled the code, executing the application for approximately 260 seconds. These are the results that I found:

- Number of `run()` loop iterations: 16765
- Average time per iteration: 16 ms
- Maximum time for all the iterations: 97 ms

Virtually 100% of this time is consumed in `drawFrame()`, especially in the calls to `lockCanvas()` and `unlockCanvasAndPost()`, which I cannot avoid making.

The weirdest part is that the maximum time for all the iterations was 97 milliseconds, far less than the delays I am noticing while executing the game. So, somehow, I believe that the problem may not be in the game loop code, but perhaps in the configuration, or somewhere else. Does anyone have any advise?

Comment: `w` and `h` are just two variables that contain the width and height of the canvas. While the view is being created they may not be initialized, and thus be zero, but after that their values does not change. Therefore, the conditional checking is always true.

Answer (score 0):

You should design your component to paint numbers and that's it.

Then you should have some other class implementing the game logic, waiting for some time and then pass a number to your UI component and ask it to paint the number.

It's a very bad idea to have UI method waiting, your game won't be responsive.

Moreover, your game logic component should do smaller waits. Wait for 100 ms, and each time, check if you waited more than 500 ms after last number was choosen.

Comment: Actually the game loop never blocks (i.e., the rendering occurs as fast as it is possible for the hardware). I know that may not be the best in terms of battery consumption, but it should give the best performance. So basically, the loop does what you said in your last paragraph (except it does not block, even for 100ms).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Use a timer task with 500ms and update your mNumberBox, and invalidate your surface.

On your surface class, within onDraw(), call mRenderer.onDraw(canvas).

This solution will not consume much cpu, will be very battery friendly, and will be much responsive.

You will also observe that your delay issues will be resolved.